# Entity framework - Return to list error?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I got the problem - `return to list` from the `entity framework`. I need to return as a object. Here is my code:

```
Public Function GetHardwareDetail() As List(Of HardwareDetailApp)
        Dim idList As New List(Of String)
        Dim Data = (From p In DB.TT_HARDWARE Select New HardwareDetailApp With {.InternalNum = p.INTERNAL_NUM, .Description = p.DESCRIPTION, .TerminalModel = p.HARDWARE_MODEL, .HardwareInternalNum = p.HARDWARE_ID, .Status = p.ISACTIVE, .Firmware = Nothing, .SerialNum = Nothing})

       If Data.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row In Data
                idList.Add(row.InternalNum)
            Next
       End If

       Dim Data2 = (From p In DB.TT_TERMINAL_HARDWARE Where idList.Contains(p.HARDWARE_INTERNAL_NUM)
              Select New HardwareDetailApp With
              {.Firmware = p.HARDWARE_FIRMWARE, .SerialNum = p.HARDWARE_SERIAL_NUM, .InternalNum = Data.FirstOrDefault.InternalNum, .Description = Data.FirstOrDefault.Description, .TerminalModel = Data.FirstOrDefault.TerminalModel, .HardwareInternalNum = Data.FirstOrDefault.HardwareInternalNum, .Status = Data.FirstOrDefault.Status})

       Return Data2.ToList
End Function
```

This is the error which I get:

> The type 'HardwareDetailApp' appears in two
>   structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to
>   Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same
>   query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and
>   those properties are set in the same order.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? All these `FirstOrDefault` calls make this a very inefficient procedure. You could build `idList` by one simple query with `ToList` and then do one query to get the data you want. But it's hard to infer your intentions, also because your question is hard to read by these uberlong lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, you have created from `HardwareDetailApp` in two place, in every creation of that you must set the same property with same order.

for example if in `linq to entity` you `Select` something like:

```
Place1:

...
Select new MyClass()
{
    PropA: 1,
}
...
```

and in that query you need to another `Select` from `MyClass` but with some other properties like `PropB`, Like:

```
Place2:

...
Select new MyClass()
{
    PropB: 2,
}
...
```

you must change all `Select` from `MyClass` into same, and set the properties you dont need to them, to its default, and set the properties in same order like:

```
Place1:

...
Select new MyClass()
{
    PropA: 1,
    PropB: default(int),
}
...
```

and

```
Place2:

...
Select new MyClass()
{
    PropA: default(int),
    PropB: 2,
}
...
```

my codes are in `c#`..

in this part of your code `Dim Data = (From p In DB.TT_HARDW ....` try to set `Firmware and SerialNum` at first like the second `select`, (i have not checked other properties carefully)